# Python 3.7 character refailure

Tags: python, concatenation

I'm quite new to python (have C,C++, Java script experience) and I run into strange behavior on pyCharm Python 3.7
I'm having a piece of code which calcs the xmodem CRC over TxBuffer and adds it to the buffer but somehow there's an extra character added.

```
TxBuffer = command + str(inverter)
CRC = CRCCCITT().calculate(TxBuffer)
print(hex(CRC))  # >>> prints 0x29b6

CRCstr = chr((CRC >> 8) & 0xff)
CRCstr += chr((CRC >> 0) & 0xff)
print(CRCstr)  # >>> prints )¶

TxBuffer += CRCstr
# TxBuffer += chr((CRC >> 8) & 0xff)
# TxBuffer += chr((CRC >> 0) & 0xff)   #line inserts \xc2 character
TxBuffer += "\r"

print(binascii.hexlify(TxBuffer.encode()))  # >>>prints b'5e503030375047533029c2b60d'
```

So, what I can't explain is why the 'c2' character is added to my data?

Best regards,

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `.encode()` is a horribly inappropriate thing to call on a 'string' that includes raw binary data.  In Python 3.x, you should be using `bytes` throughout, not `str`.

Comment: You should look into the builtin `struct` module for converting between integers and their binary representations instead of doing it by hand.

Comment: `c2` are not characters in your string, `\xc2` is a character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 3, `chr` creates a Unicode character. The call to `encode` converts to a byte string, but it must use an encoding to do so. There's only one encoding that has a 1-to-1 correspondence between Unicode code points and byte values, and that's `'latin1'`. The default is probably `'utf-8'` which will convert some code points into multi-byte sequences.

As suggested in one of the comments, this is one of those cases where you're better off working with a byte string from the start and avoiding Unicode altogether.

```
TxBuffer = TxBuffer.encode()
CRC = CRCCCITT().calculate(TxBuffer)
print(hex(CRC))   # prints 0x29b6

CRCstr = bytes([(CRC >> 8) & 0xff, (CRC >> 0) & 0xff])
print(CRCstr)   # prints b')\xb6'

TxBuffer += CRCstr
TxBuffer += b"\r"
print(binascii.hexlify(TxBuffer))   # prints b'5e503030375047533029b60d'
```

Comment: Thank you Mark, your suggestion worked. I did the .encode() at the line after "print(binascii.hexlify(TxBuffer)) "  which was a serial.write(TxBuffer.encode() ).